# How can I backup directory and files including all sub directory and files using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file named `backup.sh`. I just want to take backup only `html` directory and its all sub directories and files. But I'm getting all the parent directory of `html` directories as well like `var`, `www` which is not required for me.

I'm pasting the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Purpose = Backup of Important Data
DATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
SRCDIR="/var/www/html"
DESDIR="/media/HDD-01/html"
FILENAME=html-$DATE.tar.gz

# Making backup with compress 
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

I got this code from below link:

http://broexperts.com/2012/06/how-to-backup-files-and-directories-in-linux-using-tar-cron-jobs/

Can anyone suggest me how can I solved my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your destination path `/media/HDD-01/html` is available.

Comment: @AvinashRedy my destination path is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go for alternate: .. :)

```
#!/bin/bash
#Purpose = Backup of Important Data
DATE=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
cd /var/www/
tar -zcvf HTML-$DATE.tgz html
mv *.tgz /media/HDD-01/html
```